# Handling SIGQUIT with sigwait

Tags: c, multithreading, bash, signals, signal-handling

I'm writing a multithreaded program which needs to be terminated with the following bash line:

```
killall -QUIT -w procname
```

I decided to use a thread to receive some signals I need to handle, like SIGQUIT and SIGUSR1, and to ignore SIGQUIT in the others. 
To ignore the signal I wrote this:

```
struct sigaction s;
s.sa_handler=SIG_IGN;
if((sigaction(SIGQUIT,&s,NULL))==-1) {   
    perror("sigaction");
    return -1;
    }
```

And I wrote the following code in the thread designated to wait for signals (handlerrno is a function to check errno and exit):

```
sigset_t threadset;
int err, sig;
if(sigfillset(&threadset)==-1) handlerrno("Sigfillset thread stats");
if(sigdelset(&threadset,SIGQUIT)==-1) handlerrno("Sigdelset thread stats");
if(sigdelset(&threadset,SIGINT)==-1) handlerrno("Sigdelset thread stats");
if(sigdelset(&threadset,SIGTERM)==-1) handlerrno("Sigdelset thread stats");
if(sigdelset(&threadset,SIGUSR1)==-1) handlerrno("Sigdelset thread stats");
if((err=pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK,&threadset,NULL))!=0)        
   handlerror(err,"Set sigmask thread stats");
if((err=sigwait(&threadset,&sig))!=0) handlerror(err,"Sigwait");
//I handle the signals here
```

However, when I launch SIGQUIT from the shell, the thread designated to wait for the signals seems to be stuck in sigwait(), so I don't really know what happens and which thread gets the signal.
Is anything wrong with the code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ignore masks are process-wide. After the `sigaction` call, `SIQUIT` will never become pending in any thread and `sigwait` will therefore block forever.

What you should do is block the signal in the main thread before creating any threads, so that child threads block it too ([child threads inherit the signal mask of their parent thread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html)).

The handling thread should then be able to dequeue the signal despite it being blocked.

(I'm not sure whether your choice of terminating signal is a good one. `SIQUIT` is normally sent via `Ctrl+\` and is expected to create a core dump before terminating. Perhaps `SIGTERM` would be a better choice.)

Comment: Thanks! I need to terminate the process like this because this is an assignment for university, so our teacher gave us a test script to make sure the code works.

Anyway, the thing is that the handling thread is spawned by the main thread, so if I block it in there the handling one blocks it too right?

Comment: Correct. And if no thread has it unblocked and you only have one sigwait call active in the process, the sigwait call should get it.